# Mongodb query and count occurrence of the sub document field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My mongoDB schema sample are as the below, the `Doc` is inserted every 1 hour, the inserted time will be the `ServerTime`:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5709fd69c1aa400008ff66da"),
    Doc: {
        total: 245,
        sub-docs: [
            {
                accessedURL: "www.example.com",
                User:{
                    name: "John"
                }
                Time:{
                    ServerTime: "2016-03-30T15:45:41.296+0000",
                    FirstAccessTime: "2016-03-30T12:43:41.296+0800"
                    LastAccessTime: "2016-03-30T15:33:41.296+0800"
                }

            },
            {
                accessedURL: "www.123.com",
                User:{
                    name: "John"
                }
                Time:{
                    ServerTime: "2016-03-30T15:45:41.296+0000",
                    FirstAccessTime: "2016-03-30T12:40:41.296+0800"
                    LastAccessTime: "2016-03-30T15:23:41.296+0800"
                }

            },
            {
                accessedURL: "www.example.com",
                User:{
                    name: "Eric"
                }
                Time:{
                    ServerTime: "2016-03-30T15:45:41.296+0000",
                    FirstAccessTime: "2016-03-30T12:43:41.296+0800"
                    LastAccessTime: "2016-03-30T15:33:41.296+0800"
                }

            },
            ... # 245 sub-docs in the array
        ]
    }
}
... # more Docs
...
```

**Npte**: The `ServerTime` will be **identical** for all the `sub-docs` in the `Doc`

I want to query each `User.name` accessed URL count in the `Doc` document and Those `Doc` should fall in between a time frame based on the `Doc.sub-docs.ServerTime`,  the final output will be

```
{
    ServerTime: "2016-03-30T15:45:41.296+0000",
    sub-docs: {
        John: 3,
        Eric: 4,
        ...
    }
}
{
    ServerTime: "2016-03-30T16:45:41.296+0000",
    sub-docs: {
        John: 1,
        Eric: 2,
        ...
    }
}
...
...
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: You could use aggregation easily if you had the ServerTime at the doc level... Why embedding it on each sub-doc if it's always the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following test data as yours have some issues with commas

```
db.test.insert({
    Doc: {
        total: 245,
        sub_docs: [
            {
                accessedURL: "www.example.com",
                User:{
                    name: "John"
                },
                Time:{
                    ServerTime: "2016-03-30T15:45:41.296+0000",
                    FirstAccessTime: "2016-03-30T12:43:41.296+0800",
                    LastAccessTime: "2016-03-30T15:33:41.296+0800"
                }
            },
            {
                accessedURL: "www.123.com",
                User:{
                    name: "John"
                },
                Time:{
                    ServerTime: "2016-04-30T15:45:41.296+0000",
                    FirstAccessTime: "2016-03-30T12:40:41.296+0800",
                    LastAccessTime: "2016-03-30T15:23:41.296+0800"
                }
            },
            {
                accessedURL: "www.example.com",
                User:{
                    name: "Eric"
                },
                Time:{
                    ServerTime: "2016-03-30T15:45:41.296+0000",
                    FirstAccessTime: "2016-03-30T12:43:41.296+0800",
                    LastAccessTime: "2016-03-30T15:33:41.296+0800"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

I create this aggregation pipeline.

```
  db.test.aggregate([
    { $unwind : "$Doc.sub_docs" },
    { $group : { "_id" : "$Doc.sub_docs.Time.ServerTime" , sub_doc : { $push : "$Doc.sub_docs.User.name" } }  },
    { $unwind : "$sub_doc" },
    { $group : { "_id" : { "time" : "$_id" ,  "user" : "$sub_doc"}  , sum : {$sum : 1}} },
    { $project : { "ServerTime":  "$_id.time",  sub_docs : { user : "$_id.user" ,  visits : "$sum" }, _id : 0 }},
    { $group : { "_id" : "$ServerTime" , sub_doc : { $push : "$sub_docs" } } }
 ]);
```

The result is not exactly what you are looking for but have the same content

```
{ "_id" : "2016-04-30T15:45:41.296+0000", "sub_doc" : [ { "user" : "John", "visits" : 1 } ] }
{ "_id" : "2016-03-30T15:45:41.296+0000", "sub_doc" : [ { "user" : "Eric", "visits" : 1 }, { "user" : "John", "visits" : 1 } ] }
```

You just need to add a `$match` state before the first unwind to use this operation only in the records that match your date range. 
Also you could add the following line to set ServerTime label

```
{ $project : { "ServerTime": "$_id" ,  sub_doc : 1, "_id" : 0}}
```

Probably could be a simple pipeline but is what I have now, hope it helps.